# Mod rewrite to get ID from URL

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have the following real URL structure

```
/folder/folder2/file1.php
/folder/folder3/file2.php
```

where `file1` and `file2` could be any PHP file.

I also have

```
/folder/folder2/folder4/file1.php
/folder/folder3/folder4/file2.php
```

What I want to is change the URLs so they contain an ID like this:

```
/folder/12345/folder2/file1.php
```

What I am trying to do, is create a mod_rewrite rule that gets the ID and runs whatever the URL would be without the ID part

so

```
/folder/12345/folder2/file1.php
```

would run

```
/folder/folder2/file1.php?id=12345
```

What would the mod_rewrite rule look like to do this?

Also, what happens when I am submitting forms either as POST or GET? Can the mod rewrite work with either the post or the get?

Comment: Are you using `.htaccess` or are these directives going to be somewhere in your server config; if so, where (`<Directory>` container or vHost/Server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, from your question, that you only want to rewrite URLs of the form:

- `/folder/<id>/folder2/<anyfile.php>`
- `/folder/<id>/folder3/<anyfile.php>`

where `folder`, `folder2` and `folder3` are known subdirectories. But the `.php` file could be anything.

(This excludes `/folder/folder2/folder4/file1.php` and `/folder/folder3/folder4/file2.php` etc.)

The `<id>` is also assumed to be digits only (as in your example). If there are other constraints, such as always being 5 digits in length, then this should also be included.

You would do something like the following using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(folder)/(\d+)/(folder2|folder3)/([^./]+\.php)$ /$1/$3/$4?id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

`$n` are backreferences to the parenthsised subpatterns in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The `QSA` flag will append the query string from the request (if any) - required if you are submitting a form via GET to one of these URLs.

> Also, what happens when I am submitting forms either as POST or GET? Can the mod rewrite work with either the post or the get?

Both GET and POST requests will be rewritten.

Comment: I have got this to work, however if the page contains a link in the format <a href=file.php>test</a> then it always returns file not found, if I change the link to the full path, it will then work, is there a way to make those relative links work with the rewrite rule?

Comment: Since you are rewritting the URL from/to a different URL-path _depth_ you will need to make sure that all your internal URL-paths are either root-relative or absolute. Or use the `base` tag (perhaps). Whilst it might be theoretcially possible to construct a RewriteRule to "workaround" this for specific URLs, it's not a general fix. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters Stack for more information on this: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css